# No output after calling function (Python)

Tags: python, function

just a total newbie here. I am learning Python and was trying to call the function as below, yet I cannot see any output.

```
nums = [0,1,2,7,14]
def has_lucky_num(nums):
    #return numbers that can be divisible by 7
    for num in nums:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
        return False
has_lucky_num(nums)
```

Can someone tell me why it did not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your program doesn't actually actively print or otherwise display anything. Python won't show output unless you tell it to or use the interactive shell.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Note that the `return False` should be after the loop, not after the `if` (you must dedent it). Otherwise the code just checks the first number.

Answer (score 2):

Your program isn't printing anything because it doesn't have a `print()` command anywhere. Try the following line : `print(has_lucky_nums(nums))`, and it should print your **True** or **False** result! So you would have the following code :

```
nums = [0,1,2,7,14]
def has_lucky_num(nums):
    #return numbers that can be divisible by 7
    for num in nums:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
        return False
print(has_lucky_num(nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function has a problem:

- You must put the `return False` after loop because if you don't it return immediately after checking first item
  So function code must be this:

```py
nums = [0,1,2,7,14]
def has_lucky_num(nums):
    #return numbers that can be divisible by 7
    for num in nums:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
    return False
```

If you want to see result you must print the result returns by the function `has_lucky_num()`

So all you have to do is to add a print like this:

#### Instead Of:

```py
has_lucky_num(nums)
```

#### Replace With:

```py
print(has_lucky_num(nums))
```

#### Output:

```py
True
```

Comment: You can even `debug` the code to see the return value!

Answer (score -2):

Return True and Return False won't actually display anything. You need to do something with those values, for instance:

````
if has_lucky_num(nums) == True:
    print(f'{nums} has a lucky number!')
else:
    print(f'{nums} has a lucky number!')
```
````

Comment: You don't need to change the output from True or False to something like: `print(f'{num} is a lucky...` besides the function in the question has a return value but you changed the function!

Comment: Whoops, sleep deprived. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed!